# Redirect POST Requests with Slim 3

Tags: php, redirect, server, slim

I have an API gate in PHP with Slim 3 Framework (server1) and a web services server (server2) to access/edit the datas.

I handle user authentication and define my authenticated routes in server1. The dialog between server1 and server2 works with tokens.

I want to use my server1 to forward GET/POST requests to my server2. What is the best way to do that ?

With Slim on my server1, I can use the withRedirect method but I can't make it work with POST requests :

```
$app->post('/api/resource', function ($request, $response, $args) {
   return $response->withRedirect("http://server2/api/resource?additionla_parameter=value");
});
```

Maybe should I use an app like Guzzle or a proxy ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally would go the Guzzle route, meaning to just create a client on the server-side to communicate with server2, but there actually is a HTTP 307 response code for such purposes. It states that a client should not change the method (in your case the POST) during a redirect. Here is a nice little wrap-up: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect/99966#99966

I just peeked at the slim source and the method accepts a second parameter for the status code which defaults to 302 when not set. See https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/Slim/Http/Response.php#L289. So just try this:

```
$response->withRedirect("http://postplease", 307);
```

That might work

Comment: It perfectly works ! I'll check the Guzzle implementation though because it seems to be a cleaner way. Thanks !